# jenkins deploy plugin. out of memory

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, jenkins

I use Jenkins with deploy plugin, maven3 and tomcat7. Previously all worked fine, but new `.war` with new libraries cause `OutOfMemoryError` (java heap size) exception during **deploying**.

***Note: building was successfully***

This issue caused only if I use jenkins. If I try to deploy `.war` file (that was placed in `/tomcat/webapps` by jenkins) manually directly from tomcat manager - all works fine. Or if I restart tomcat and `.war` will be auto deployed - all works fine.

I increased the java heap memory for tomcat in /etc/default/tomcat7 and issue was fixed, but in my opinion it's bad solution. Why OutOfMemory happens using jenkins?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins gets an OutOfMemoryException when the Maven job you're running is out of memory. Every Maven buildstep in a Jenkins job will be run separately, so every step can have it's own settings. To fix this issue, you can assign more memory to a specific Maven build step.

When a build contains a "Invoke a top-level Maven targets" buildstep there is the option to ajust the JVM options (this can be found after clicking the advanced button). When assigning more memory (for instance -Xmx1024m -Xms256m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m) the specified buildstep will less likely run out of memory. If it still does, you should play with the numbers.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for answer. Jenkins get NOT outOfMemory exception. Jenkins get ContainerException from Tomcat.  In jenkins job Maven build was finish without any exceptions. And output .war file is fine. But next step in Jenkins is deploying of this .war file. And during deploying tomcat get OutOfMemoryError and stopps jenkins job. If i get .war file that was compiled in previous step and deploy them manualy - all works fine.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. Maybe this is what you're looking for: http://frankkieviet.blogspot.ca/2006/10/classloader-leaks-dreaded-permgen-space.html